# Can't override settings in Scrapy after the init function of a spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Is it possible to override Scrapy settings after the init function of a spider?
For example if I want to get settings from db and I pass my query parameters as arguments from the cmdline.

```
def __init__(self, spider_id, **kwargs):
    self.spider_id = spider_id
    self.set_params(spider_id)
    super(Base_Crawler, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def set_params(self):
   #TODO
   #makes a query in db
   #get set variables from query result
   #override settings
```

Comment: can you post the class around `__init__`, especially from which other class it derives?

Comment: No, you can't override settings on the fly, but you could pass class parameters that will help you in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can "override" settings after initialization of spider however it would affect nothing because most of them applied earlier.

What you can actually do is to pass parameters to Spider as command-line options using `-a` and override project settings using `-s`, for ex.)

**Spider:**

```
class TheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'thespider'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.spider_id = kwargs.pop('spider_id', None)
       super(TheSpider).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**CLI**:

```
scrapy crawl thespider -a spider_id=XXX -s SETTTING_TO_OVERRIDE=YYY
```

If you need something more advanced consider to write custom runner wrapping your spider. Below is example from the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script):

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

# 'followall' is the name of one of the spiders of the project.
process.crawl('followall', domain='scrapinghub.com')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Just replace `get_project_settings` with your own routine that returns [Settings](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/settings/__init__.py#L447) instance.

Anyway, avoid of overloading of spider's code with non-scraping logic to keep it clean and reusable.